# reconsume Kafka 0.10.1 topic in Spring

Tags: spring, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

In Spring-Kafka I want to reconsume a Kafka topic from the beginning. Doing this by changing the `group.id` to something unknown to Kafka of course works:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "sensordata.t")
public void receiveMessage(String message) {
...
}

@Bean
public Map consumerConfigs() {
    Map props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "NewGroupID");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false"); //it still commits though...
    return props;
}
```

However, starting over by setting the offset to 0 fails.

```
@KafkaListener(topicPartitions =
{ @TopicPartition(topic = "sensordata.t",
        partitionOffsets = @PartitionOffset(partition = "0", initialOffset = "0"))})
public void receiveMessage(String message) {
...
}

@Bean
public Map consumerConfigs() {
    Map props = new HashMap<>();
    ...
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "NewGroupID");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "10000"); //making timeout window larger seems to have no influence
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, "1"); //setting max records to 1 makes no difference
    return props;
}
```

The error I get:

```
2016-11-14 14:07:59.018  INFO 8165 --- [           main] c.i.t.s.server.SpringKafkaApplication    : Started SpringKafkaApplication in 4.134 seconds (JVM running for 4.745)
2016-11-14 14:07:59.125  INFO 8165 --- [afka-consumer-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : Discovered coordinator bto:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) for group spring8.
2016-11-14 14:07:59.125  INFO 8165 --- [afka-consumer-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : Discovered coordinator bto:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) for group spring8.
2016-11-14 14:07:59.129  INFO 8165 --- [afka-consumer-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : Revoking previously assigned partitions [] for group spring8
2016-11-14 14:07:59.129  INFO 8165 --- [afka-consumer-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions revoked:[]
2016-11-14 14:07:59.129  INFO 8165 --- [afka-consumer-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : (Re-)joining group spring8
2016-11-14 14:07:59.338 ERROR 8165 --- [afka-consumer-1] essageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer : Container exception

org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured session.timeout.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing the session timeout or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator$OffsetCommitResponseHandler.handle(ConsumerCoordinator.java:600) ~[kafka-clients-0.10.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator$OffsetCommitResponseHandler.handle(ConsumerCoordinator.java:541) ~[kafka-clients-0.10.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$CoordinatorResponseHandler.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:679) ~[kafka-clients-0.10.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$CoordinatorResponseHandler.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:658) ~[kafka-clients-0.10.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture$1.onSuccess(RequestFuture.java:167) ~[kafka-clients-0.10.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.fireSuccess(RequestFuture.java:133) ~[kafka-clients-0.10.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.complete(RequestFuture.java:107) ~[kafka-clients-0.10.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient$RequestFutureCompletionHandler.onComplete(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:426) ~[kafka-clients-0.10.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:278) ~[kafka-clients-0.10.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.clientPoll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:360) ~[kafka-clients-0.10.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:224) ~[kafka-clients-0.10.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:192) ~[kafka-clients-0.10.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:163) ~[kafka-clients-0.10.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.commitOffsetsSync(ConsumerCoordinator.java:426) ~[kafka-clients-0.10.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.commitSync(KafkaConsumer.java:1059) ~[kafka-clients-0.10.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.commitIfNecessary(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:939) ~[spring-kafka-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.processCommits(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:816) ~[spring-kafka-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:526) ~[spring-kafka-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_92]
```

Anyone familiar with this?

I'm using `Kafka 0.10.1.0` and

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-kafka.version>1.1.1.RELEASE</spring-kafka.version>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why have you decided that it is the problem of offset `0`? 
Your StackTrace says that you have longer `pollTimeout` is longer than `session.timeout.ms`:

> Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured session.timeout.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing the session timeout or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.

How about to adjust them properly?

Comment: I haven't. But I do set the timeout to 10 seconds and max batch size to 1, and this error pops up within a couple of seconds (<10).

Comment: Also, not mangling with the offset does not result in an error. No need to adjust timeout of batchsize.

Comment: OK. Would be better if you come up with some simple Spring Boot application to play from our side. Your stacktrace isn't related to the `initPartitionsIfNeeded()`, therefore that is unclear how the `0` may effect regular `poll()` and `commitSync()`

Comment: Ok. I'll come back when I can narrow down the problem

Comment: There's something wrong with this picture - when using `@TopicPartition` you are manually assigning the partitions so a rebalance shouldn't occur - are you mixing consumers? (Some manual, some broker assignment). If using broker assignment, you can use the [seek mechanism](http://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/1.1.1.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#seek) to reset offsets.